# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ,

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, syntax-error

I'm getting this syntax error in react:

```js
Unexpected token, expected , (22:4)

  20 |           </div>
  21 |       </div>
> 22 |   )}
     |    ^
  23 |      </section>
  24 |    );
  25 |  }
```

I've looked at every tag and bracket multiple times through, to see if all had their opening and closing tag/bracket, and I can't seem to find the error. It could be something else, but I'm not good enough in javascript to spot the mistake.

I don't understand the error message either, what excactly does it mean when it says "expected ,"?

Here is the code the error message refering to:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dropdownlist from './dropdowndata';

class Links extends Component {
 render() {
     return (
     <section>
      { dropdownlist.map(drop =>(
        <div className="dropdown">
        <button className="dropdownhover"> {drop.name} </button>
        <div className="links">
        
        drop.button.map(button => (
     <div className="linkssection">
       <h2> {button.title} </h2>
       <ul><li><a className="singlelink" href={button.url}>{button.urlText}</a></li></ul>
     </div>
        ))
     
        </div>
        </div>
   )}
  </section>
  );
 }
}

export default Links;
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You haven't closed your outer `map` function parentheses. Try `</div> ))}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the first map function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dropdownlist from './dropdowndata';

class Links extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <section>
            { dropdownlist.map(drop =>(
              <div className="dropdown">
              <button className="dropdownhover"> {drop.name} </button>
              <div className="links">

              drop.button.map(button => (
              <div className="linkssection">
                <h2> {button.title} </h2>
                <ul><li><a className="singlelink" href={button.url}>{button.urlText}</a></li></ul>
              </div>
              ))

              </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Links;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for both your answers, both your solutions fixed something wrong there. I wish I could mark both as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Proper indentation helps in fixing issues like these :)

Close the map function as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dropdownlist from './dropdowndata';

class Links extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        {dropdownlist.map(drop =>(
          <div className="dropdown">
            <button className="dropdownhover"> {drop.name} </button>
            <div className="links">
              {drop.button.map(button => (
                <div className="linkssection">
                  <h2> {button.title} </h2>
                  <ul><li><a className="singlelink" href={button.url}>{button.urlText}</a></li></ul>
                </div>
              ))} // <-- close here
            </div>
          </div>
        } // <-- fixed
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Links;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for both your answers, both your solutions fixed something wrong there. I wish I could mark both as correct :)

Comment: @zipfstein you can always upvote the answer if you cant mark as accepted :)